# Python GTK+: create custom signals?

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk

Is it possible to create new signals in Python GTK+ ?

I'd like a skeleton code example, please.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, it broke my 10k barrier which has been holding all evening for some weird reason.

Comment: @Aiden: my pleasure: sorry I don't have upvotes left today (quota reached early).

Comment: No worries, pushing me into 'k' territory is thanks enough!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An excerpt:

> **Creating your own signals**
>
> The other thing you probably want to
>   use when subclassing GObject is define
>   custom signals. You can create your
>   own signals that can be emitted so
>   users of your class can connect to
>   them.
>
> When a signal is emitted a set of
>   closures will be executed. A closure
>   is an abstraction of the callback
>   concept. A closure is the callback
>   itself (a function pointer), the user
>   data (it will be the last parameter to
>   the callback) and another function for
>   cleanup issues, which will not be
>   discussed in this document.
>
> For the sake of this article you don't
>   really need to know the difference
>   between a callback and a closure so
>   both terms will be used. But be
>   advised that this is not totally
>   correct.
>
> As we said before, when a signal is
>   emitted, a set of closures will be
>   executed. One of them is the same one
>   for all the instances of this class
>   and hence its name: the class closure,
>   and the other ones are custom user
>   callbacks. Note that not all the
>   signals need to have a class closure
>   because it is optional.

From, http://www.pygtk.org/articles/subclassing-gobject/sub-classing-gobject-in-python.htm, hope that helps. There is example code on the site and [here](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/~chrbecke/gobject-tutorial/car4.py) , a snippet:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gobject

class Car(gobject.GObject):
    __gproperties__ = {
        'fuel' : (gobject.TYPE_FLOAT, 'fuel of the car',
                  'amount of fuel that remains in the tank',
                  0, 60, 50, gobject.PARAM_READWRITE)
        }

    __gsignals__ = {
        'engine-started' : (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, gobject.TYPE_NONE,
                            (gobject.TYPE_FLOAT,))
        }

    def __init__(self):
        gobject.GObject.__init__(self)
        self.fuel = 50

    def do_get_property(self, property):
        if property.name == 'fuel':
            return self.fuel
        else:
            raise AttributeError, 'unknown property %s' % property.name

    def do_set_property(self, property, value):
        if property.name == 'fuel':
            self.fuel = value
        else:
            raise AttributeError, 'unknown property %s' % property.name

    def do_engine_started(self, remaining_fuel):
        print '***** Beginning of class closure *****'
        print 'The engine is ready and we still have %f of fuel' % self.fuel
        print '***** End of class closure *****'

    def start(self):
        self.emit('engine-started', self.get_property('fuel'))

gobject.type_register(Car)
```

Comment: hmmm... how did I miss this during my googling session... thanks!

Comment: The pleasure is all mine re: your 10K barrier. See you around.

Answer (score 4):

The answers are correct of course, but using [libraries](http://bitbucket.org/aafshar/pygtkhelpers-main/) is less prone to pains:

```
import gobject

from pygtkhelpers.utils import gsignal

class Car(gobject.GObject):

    gsignal('engine-started', float) # yeah baby
```